# Dynamically load a template in a Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I want to dynamically load a component's template in runtime in Svelte. Basically download some user-defined template and use that to build out the component in run-time. Is this actually possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to include the Svelte compiler and use that to compile the template. You could check out how the [REPL's repository](https://github.com/sveltejs/sites/tree/master/packages/repl) sets that up.

The REPL performs two major steps:

- Convert the code to a raw component which still references `'svelte/internal'`
- Bundle the component so all referenced code is included via Rollup

The first step is easy, you just do something like this:

```js
import { compile } from 'svelte/compiler';

const { js, css } = compile(template, {
  filename: 'Component.svelte',
  format: 'esm',
});

console.log(js.code, css.code);
```

The bundling is a bit more involved (see its [worker's code](https://github.com/sveltejs/sites/blob/589c295fc80557636333bb2c86115776f74a855f/packages/repl/src/lib/workers/bundler/index.js)). You could however, make the internals available for the `import` and just run the code directly.

E.g. using unpkg.com for testing and throwing the code into an `iframe.srcdoc`:

```js
const code = `
    ${js.code.replace(
        'svelte/internal',
        'https://unpkg.com/svelte@3.49.0/internal/index.mjs',
    )}

    new Component({ target: document.body });
`;

srcdoc = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Svelte App</title>
            <${''}style>${css.code}</${''}style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <${''}script type="module">${code}</${''}script>
        </body>
    </html>
`;
```

(The tags are split using `${}` because the Svelte parser will break otherwise.)

You could also insert the code directly into your document via a new module script, you just have to identify the target element somehow, e.g. by generating a unique random ID.

Here is something neat you can do to directly use the generated code: Dynamically `import` the script from a `Blob`.

```js
const componentSrc = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([code], { type: 'text/javascript' })
);
const { default: Component } = await import(componentSrc);
URL.revokeObjectURL(componentSrc);

new Component({ target: ... });
```

If you use the component outside a sandboxed `iframe`, you should be aware of the XSS risk that you expose yourself to.

Comment: Hey this is absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much! I had a question though, could this method be used to handle dependencies? As in, the `template` variable, could it have imports that bring in other Svelte components? And if so, how would I handle this?

Comment: Depends on where the components come from. If the component is already compiled including all its dependencies, then you can just import the component like any other. E.g. if you want to import `carbon-components-svelte` via unpkg, that would currently not work directly, because it has a live dependency on `flatpickr`. Other components, e.g. `@bulatdashiev/svelte-slider` have no dependencies and could be imported directly. If you want to import components from your current site, you probably should set up your build system such, that they are compiled as independent assets.