# Svelte bindings within template literals

Tags: svelte

I am trying to bind the textarea element inside a template string. But when i console.log the binded element, I get undefined. Does svelte bindings work inside template string?

```
let el 

var html = `

<textarea type="text" df-name rows="5" class="auto_height bg-transparent text-xl focus:outline-none resize-none " bind:this=${el} on:input=${ console.log(el)}>
`;

//console.log output 'undefined'
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [Dynamically load a template in a Svelte component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338240/dynamically-load-a-template-in-a-svelte-component)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, it will not be compiled and none of the Svelte features will be available.

Comment: Please provide constructive solutions for this asked issue.

Comment: I answered the question that was asked and linked to a duplicate in a comment to the question.