# How to bind compiled result of string to component in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am trying to write a component which has a source string property. Then, users can set the source and my component compiles and renders the source.

Both SPA and SSR should be supported for compiling and rendering.

Here is the usage of my component in `App.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import Preview from './Preview.svelte'
    const source = '<div {...$$restProps}><slot /></div>'
    let name = 'world';
</script>

<Preview {source}>Hello {name}!</Preview>
```

And the `Preview.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import { compile } from 'svelte/compiler'
    export let source
    const cmp = compile(source, {
        filename: 'Component.svelte',
        format: 'esm',
        // generate: 'ssr'
    })
    console.log(cmp.js.code, cmp.css.code)
</script>
```

How can I bind the compiled result to a component?

I am thinking something like this:

```
<svelte:component this={cmp.something} />
```

I tried the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/de9c24f562e14e15b2617611e4d72b24?version=3.55.1), but it has error:

*Could not load https://unpkg.com/svelte@3.55.1/compiler/index.mjs (imported by ./Preview.svelte): Cannot find "/compiler/index.mjs" in svelte@3.55.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import the compiler like that in the REPL because it does not respect the exports of the `package.json`. It falsely assumes that `svelte/compiler` refers to a directory, though the files are at the package root:

```json
"exports": {
    // ...
    "./compiler": {
      "types": "./types/compiler/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./compiler.mjs",
      "require": "./compiler.js"
    },
}
```

The given code works as expected locally e.g. in a SvelteKit project.

As a workaround you can change the import to a full URL:

```js
import { compile } from 'https://unpkg.com/svelte@3.55.1/compiler.mjs';
```

How to one can load the compiled component code is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73339006/546730).

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway that I can do in REPL?

Comment: Do what? I wrote how to fix the import and my other answer gives an outline of how to use the compiled code. You might not be able to use slots and insert the component directly/via `<svelte:component>`. It works via an action though ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/9716b558273d4ab896b515e33fae29b0?version=3.55.1)). Would not really recommend this approach anyway. Do you really need all those Svelte features?

Comment: I have to develop a CMS and I love Svelte! I'm trying to do solve some challenges using Svelte/Sveltekit. Site admins should be able to update the contents (lets say Blog, News, etc.) and change the template (HTML structure) of some sections and the data comes from DB/API. Any idea on dynamically compile template fetched from API and binding the data? Assume I have a json containing HTML template and also data object to be bound to the same template.

Comment: The template just has to contain exports and the data has to be passed to the `props` of the component constructor. I updated the above REPL with an example passing all `$$respProps`.